# osmfhls player does not resume video after finishing advertisement

Tags: javascript

I'm using osmfhls player and I'm trying to show a preroll advertisement with this config recommended in it's documentation:

http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/docs/grind/#ads

```
player.displayAd({
                       id: "showVideoPrerollAd",
                       url: "http://video.test.com:1935/vod/50.mp4/chunklist.m3u8",
                       hideScrubBarWhilePlayingAd: true,
                       resumePlaybackAfterAd: true,
                       pauseMainMediaWhilePlayingAd: true,
                       clickUrl: "http://osmfhls.kutu.ru",
                       closable: false
                   });
```

My problem is it doesn't resume or play the video after the advertisement ends.
it doesn't have any errors, even when I try it myself manually on finished advertisement to play with

> player.play();

it wouldn't start
any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used play2() instead of play()